# Python matching greedy phrase search.

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex match requirement. I want to match a complete phrase instead of individual subtokens. here's an example

```
In [21]: re.findall(r"""don't|agree|don't agree""", "I don't agree to this", re.IGNORECASE)
Out[21]: ["don't", 'agree']
```

I want this to match `"don't agree"` and not `don't and agree` separately.

Any help.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just find the phrase "don't agree" and then split it on the space.

Answer (score 2):

Put the longest string before:

```
re.findall(r"don't agree|don't|agree", "I don't agree to this", re.IGNORECASE)
```

or use an optional group:

```
re.findall(r"don't(?: agree)?|agree", "I don't agree to this", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaround in your regex:

```
re.findall(r"""don't(?!\sagree)|(?<!don't\s)agree|don't agree""", "I don't agree to this", re.IGNORECASE)
                     ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Using negative lookahead `(?!\sagree)` it checking that no `agree` after the `don't`.

And using negative lookbehind `(?<!don't\s)` its checking that there is no `don't` before the `agree`